# Detect and Fill any Webpage form with Selenium-Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium

I'm kind of new to Selenium testing. I want to use Selenium to detect forms in any webpage and also fill them. I don't want to be restricted to a single webpage like having to inspect the page or view page source to get an id or name or Xpath.

I just want to be able to input any webpage URL, selenium should detect a form, fill it and submit. For example, a registration or login form in any webpage. Thanks.

NB: I'm working with python please.

Answer (score 3):

There are no out of the box solutions, as far as I know, for your stated problem. Mainly because your problem is too broad.

Selenium can't detect "forms" unless you tell it what forms are. To do that you need to find an identifiable CSS or XPATH selector for all the elements on any webpage that could qualify as a form input field.

Furthermore, filling every possible input field in a form with acceptable input is something you can only do if you know how a webpage classifies "good" and "bad" input. Selenium can't make that choice for you.

Submitting a form can be done in multiple ways, most webpages use a "Submit" or similar button. Selenium can't automatically detect that button is and press it for you, you need to tell it where that button is on the page via a selector.

I would suggest reading a bit more on what Selenium is and what it can do. There are multiple python/selenium tutorials available. I would first start reading about the bindings available in the python implementation for Selenium if you chose python to be your scripting language of choice for your work. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Comment: I actually want to build a complete test software that can test multiple sites .

Comment: First of all, no amount of code can "test" a site, but that's a much broader discussion. For reference see http://www.satisfice.com/articles/cdt-automation.pdf. Secondly, assuming what you meant was "I want to write some code that runs a set of automated checks against some list of websites I arbitrarily define", then there is no freely available plugin solution to do that. You will need to define the checks, define pass/fail criterias for them and aggregate your test results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually want to build a complete test software that can test multiple sites. I want to be able to write tests that can be work for any site not just a particular website cause i'm being limited by element ID, Name etc. That's why i wanted starting from the very basic stuffs like form registration and login. I actually gained my previous knowledge of selenium from that link http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html. Would still appreciate your help in any way you can.

Comment: The thing that is limiting you from reaching a conclusion is your understanding of how broad your problem is. Also, your approach to solving your problem with punctual solutions that may or may not help you reach a conclusion will most likely lead you to wrong conclusions. My answers tried to help you redefine the problem to a simpler one. One that, in my opinion, could have a solution.

Comment: Here's a simple example. Say we want to automatically test a user can login into all the websites in the following list: [www.google.com, www.test.com]. How would you go about testing that without a script? What could be considered a pass scenario for a successful login. What would be a fail scenario? What scenarios can you build that might result in an error on the site? How would you test if say 200 users try to simultaneously log in? How would you try to access a page that you shouldnt unless logged in. How would you test if every information about your user is correct after login?

Comment: so are you saying that what i'm trying to achieve is impossible with selenium?

Comment: I'm trying to help you understand the complexity of your endeavor. With enough work and enough time, one can move a mountain. Writing selectors and heuristics to detect, fill any and all possible combinations and input fields or click buttons devised by human minds is not impossible. It is just a really really lot of work. The tricky part of testing is not clicking a button or finding a field tho.

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at the documentation here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html)

You probably want to do something like:

```
all_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")
for input in all_inputs:
   input.sendKeys("my password")
```

Comment: Thank you. this was able to select all the inputs at once and fill them with "my password". But that's not what i want exactly...how does it fill firstname, lastname, email.....what if its a checkbox?

Answer (score -1):

Try to verify the structure and generate patterns by hierarchy:

Also you know, there is a form element that contains all elements into the form, so for example:

url : https://kenoshasmiles.com/contact

1. go to the website and execute this code on console:
   Check the pattern in order to get all posibles ways to fill any form on any web page, its my approach for this solution:
   Father > child > child > child > child > value => match with label "Name"

```js
let element = document.getElementsByTagName('form')                     
for(item in element){ 
    for(child in element[item].children){ 
      for(subchild in element[item].children[child].children){ 
        for( kid in element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children){ 
          //structure: form > div > div > div > div > value
          for( subkid in element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children){ 
            // iterate over subkids childrens
            for( last in element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children){               

              //element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "James"
              //console.log(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])

              //pattern name
             
              if(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].innerText.includes('Name') || element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].innerText.includes('Name')){
                element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "Jose Jose"
                console.log('Name > ', element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])
              }
           
              //pattern email
              if(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].innerText.includes('email') || element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].innerText.includes('Email')){
                element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "jose@gmail.com"
                console.log('Email > ',element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])
              }

              //pattern Phone
              if(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].innerText.includes('Phone') || element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].innerText.includes('Phone')){
                element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "887446714"
                console.log('Email > ',element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])
              }


              //pattern Phone
              if(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].innerText.includes('Contact Reason') || element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].innerText.includes('Contact Reason')){
                element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "Appoinment"
                console.log('Contact Reason > ',element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])
              }

                 //pattern Comments
              if(element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].innerText.includes('Comments') || element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].innerText.includes('Comments')){
                element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last].value = "Hi, My name is Jose."
                console.log('Comments > ',element[item].children[child].children[subchild].children[kid].children[subkid].children[last])
              }

              
          }
        }
      } 
    } 
  }  
}
```